# Cocoa butter sauce for beverages that doesn't resolidify

Tags: sauce, drinks, cocoa

I'd like to make a cocoa butter sauce flavoring for beverages with the following properties:

1. Stays as close to pure cocoa butter as possible.
2. Doesn't re-solidify when drink is cold.
3. Prefer not to use emulsifiers, but will if really necessary.
4. Uses as natural ingredients as possible.

Comment: I think you are asking for something that isn't possible. Cocoa butter is a fat which solidifies below 34C (roughly), you can't change that physical property. What effect are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I think GdD's consideration is irrelevant here. There is no theoretical reason why it won't be possible. You'd simply need to make an eutectic system with another fat. But I don't know which other fat would be suitable here, especially with the "cold" requirement (the exact temperature would be important, achieving it at room temp would be much easier than in an iced chocolate). Also, I don't think you will get away with no emulsifiers for a beverage, unless you want to drink something made entirely out of fat.

Comment: The best way to make a fat not resolidify upon cooling is to make a recipe rely on it resolidifying upon cooling :) Is this intended as a "sauce" (stays on top/bottom of a cocktail) or "flavouring" (blended into the drink)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be looking for "white chocolate" rather than pure cocoa butter. Cocoa butter doesn't have a huge amount of flavor; it's added to things largely for its texture. At the very least it generally needs sugar and vanilla.

Ghirardelli and Torani both make white chocolate sauces. Is that what you're after? You can make your own by dissolving white chocolate in sweetened condensed milk, which is dense enough that you don't need an emulsifier if you grate it finely and stir.

I'd use this recipe as a starting point. (Omit the coffee powder)
http://www.food.com/recipe/white-chocolate-mocha-syrup-recipe-376916